# MySQL statement for insert if does not exist else update

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert multiple rows at the same time and check if they are exist. I want to update if they are exist, otherwise insert.

My primary key is "ID".
I don't want to use unique index for "query" column.

What I want to insert/update :

```
INSERT INTO my_table (query, keyword) VALUES ('home', 'home-link');
INSERT INTO my_table (query, keyword) VALUES ('contact', 'contact-link');
```

my table:

```
--------------------------------
ID |  query   |  keyword       |
--------------------------------
1  |  home    |  home-link     |
--------------------------------
2  |  contact |  contact-link  |
--------------------------------
```

I have tried that but it gives me SQL syntax error #1064:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT query FROM my_table WHERE query='home')
THEN
UPDATE my_table SET query='home' AND keyword='home-link' WHERE query='home'
ELSE
INSERT INTO my_table (query, keyword) VALUES ('home', 'home-link')
END IF


IF EXISTS(SELECT query FROM my_table WHERE query='contact')
THEN
UPDATE my_table SET query='contact' AND keyword='contact-link' WHERE query='contact'
ELSE
INSERT INTO my_table (query, keyword) VALUES ('contact', 'contact-link')
END IF
```

Comment: Why is it not possible to add a primary key or at least a unique key, so that you can use `insert ... on duplicate key update ...`?

Answer (score 2):

I have decided to delete the record and then insert the new one

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE query = 'home';
INSERT INTO my_table (query, keyword) VALUES ('home', 'home-link');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a unique index on the `query` column in your table, you can do an upsert like this:

```
insert into my_table (query, keyword) values ('home', 'home-link')
on duplicate key update 
keyword = values(keyword)
```

More info: 
http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/09/30/how-to-do-an-upsert-in-mysql/

Comment: Unfortunately I have primary key index for ID (auto increment)

Comment: You can still add a unique index on the `query` column, assuming you want to enforce uniqueness on that column.

Comment: Certainly I want to make the query unique and update if it exists but since I am going to use it for opencart, I don't want to mess up the table. Is it possible to do it without adding unique index?

Comment: @Dejavu no, on duplicate key update works with primary key or unique index only.

Comment: What about with IF ELSE statement ?

Comment: IF ELSE is not supported in standard MySQL queries. See my other answer.

Comment: @Dejavu how would a unique index mess up a table? Is this table used by other scripts as well, that were not developed by you and may be trying to insert the same value into query column?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add a unique index to the `query` column, then you can't do an upsert using only SQL. The conditional syntax you tried is not supported.

You could write a stored procedure to do this, or use a scripting language (bash, python, etc).

Another option is to install [common_schema](https://code.google.com/archive/p/common-schema/) and use the [conditional logic in QueryScript](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/query_script_if_else.html). Here's an example using common_schema QueryScript:

```
call common_schema.run("
  if (
  select count(*)=0 
  from test.my_table 
  where query='home'
  )
  {
    insert into test.my_table (query, keyword) values ('home', 'home-link');
  }
  else
  {
    update test.my_table set keyword='home-link' where query='home';
  }
");
```

Comment: Ok now I see how it works. I think first I'll delete the row then insert the new one :)

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually there is no problem with the approach of using an if-else statement for this.
The error is caused by the if-else syntax used in the provided SQL.

The correct if-else syntax would be (Note the different use of keywords):

```
IF (Expression )
BEGIN
  -- If the condition is TRUE then execute the following statement
  True Statements;
END
 
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- If the condition is False then execute the following statement
  False Statements;
END
```

Code from: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-if-statement-introduction-and-overview/